# plpgsql: extend new row in trigger function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table "messages". And for each INSERT'ed row i must INSERT several copies of this row in same table "messages" (for mass mailing). I make a trigger for it (for example for one copy).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO messages (some_field) VALUES (NEW.some_value_copy)
 RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER some_tg BEFORE INSERT ON messages FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE some_trigger();
```

How can i extend NEW to 
`INSERT INTO messages (some_field) VALUES (NEW.some_value),(NEW.some_value_copy)` ?
thx

Comment: Are you saying that you want to *duplicate* each row inserted into a table? What's the PostgreSQL version? What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Yes, more exact goal would be nice

Comment: Yes, i'm trying duplicate it. ver. 9.2. Actually rows are little bit different. Every row - it's exemplar of message owned by user.

Comment: The problem is an anti-pattern for a trigger, since it will not know how many copies are required, nor should it. Unless it's forced upon you, use something else, like A FOR LOOP on inserting in a plpgsql function, or pending that, a loop in the client code.

Answer (score 1):

Still don't know your schema, so it's hard to help, but I think you could do something close to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ins_messages()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
 if NEW.usr is not null then
    return NEW; -- making actual insert
 end if;
 if NEW.sender <> '-1' then
    insert into messages (message, usr, sender, receiver)
    values
     (NEW.message, NEW.sender, NEW.sender, NEW.receiver),
     (NEW.message, NEW.receiver, NEW.sender, NEW.receiver);
 else
    insert into messages (message, usr, sender, receiver)
    select NEW.message, name, NEW.sender, name
    from users;
 end if;
 return null;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/26984/2)

Comment: It will make a recursion) Moreover - if i want to add 100 rows?)

Comment: update solution for 100 rows :) have to check about recursion

Comment: Count of rows are dynamically changes)

Comment: well I don't think I can guess what you want to do with this trigger, update your question to show your actual goal

Comment: Well, as i said - another `INSERT` in function will trigger this function)

Comment: you can compare OLD and NEW rows to avoid recursion but I can't understand your task completely

Comment: Well, i have to make trigger for private_messages system. Because then user send a message to another, it's should create TWO rows in table "messages". One for sender, one for receiver. And also, this function should allow make mass mailing. So, for example - i put '-1' in sender field, and for every user creates a row in table. Now i trying to make it with execute, but have some troubles with understanding it.

Comment: It's possible to check that this message already exists for sender = NEW.receiver and receiver = NEW.sender, but in my expirience problems like this arise when you have not very good database deign. Why do you want to copy message for receiver? you can fetch all messages with union later for example, or store senders and receivers in one `messages_users` table

Comment: Well, unfortunately, it is not my requirements.

Comment: @user2641789 check updated answer, still trying to guess your schema :)